# How to prevent race conditions in a web application?

Tags: database, web-applications

Consider an e-commerce site, where Alice and Bob are both editing the product listings. Alice is improving descriptions, while Bob is updating prices. They start editing the Acme Wonder Widget at the same time. Bob finishes first and saves the product with the new price. Alice takes a bit longer to update the description, and when she finishes, she saves the product with her new description. Unfortunately, she also overwrites the price with the old price, which was not intended.

In my experience, these issues are extremely common in web apps. Some software (e.g. wiki software) does have protection against this - usually the second save fails with "the page was updated while you were editing". But most web sites do not have this protection.

It's worth noting that the controller methods are thread-safe in themselves. Usually they use database transactions, which make them safe in the sense that if Alice and Bob try to save at the precise same moment, it won't cause corruption. The race condition arises from Alice or Bob having stale data in their browser.

How can we prevent such race conditions? In particular, I'd like to know:

- What techniques can be used? e.g. tracking the time of last change. What are the pros and cons of each.
- What is a helpful user experience?
- What frameworks have this protection built in?

Comment: You've already given the answer: by tracking the date of change of objects and comparing it to the age of the data that other changes try to update. Do you want to know something else, e.g. how to do it efficiently?

Comment: @KilianFoth - I've added some info about what I'd particularly like to know

Comment: Your question is in no way special to web applications, desktop applications can have exactly the same problem. The typical solution strategies are described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129329/optimistic-vs-pessimistic-locking

Comment: FYI, the form of locking you mention in your question is known as "[optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)"

Comment: Some discussion related to Django [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/pZCk4cFVcSI)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to "read your writes", which means before you write down a change, you need to read the record again and check if any changes where made to it since you last read it. You can do this field-by-field (fine-grained) or based on a timestamp (coarse-grained). While you do this check you need an exclusive lock on the record.
If no changes were made, you can write down your changes and release the lock. If the record has changed in the meantime, you abort the transaction, release the lock and notify the user.

Comment: This sounds like the most practical approach. Do you know of any frameworks that implement this? I think the biggest problem with this scheme is that a simple "edit conflict" message will frustrate users, but attempting to merge the changesets (manually or automatically) is difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any frameworks that supports this out of the box. I don't think an edit confilict error message will be perceived as to frustrating, as long as it doesn't come up to often. Ultimately, it depends on the user load of the system wether you just check the timestamp or implement a more complex merging function.

Comment: I maintained a PC distributed database product that used the fine-grained approach (against its local database copy): if one user changed the price and the other changed the description - no problem! Just like in real life. If two users changed the price - 2nd user gets an apology and tries their change again. No problem! This does not require locks except during the moment when data is being written to the database. It doesn't matter if one user goes to lunch while their change is on the screen and submits it later. For remote database changes, it was based on record timestamps.

Comment: Dataflex had a function called "reread()" which does what you describe. In the later versions, it was safe in a multiuser environment. And, indeed, it was the only way to get such interleaved updates to work.

Comment: can you give an example of how to do this with sql server?\

Answer (score 11):

I have seen 2 main ways:

1. Add the timestamp of the last update of the page the use is editing in a hidden input. When committing the timestamp is checked against the current one and if they don't match it has been updated by someone else and return an error.

   - pro: multiple users can edit different parts of the page. The error page can lead to a diff page where the second user can merge his changes in the new page.
   - con: sometime large parts of effort gets wasted during large concurrent edits.
2. When a user starts editing the page lock it for a reasonable amount of time, when another user then tries to edit he gets an error page and has to wait until either the lock expires or the first user has committed.

   - pro: edit efforts are not wasted.
   - con: an unscrupulous user can lock a page indefinitely. A page with an expired lock may still be able to commit unless otherwise dealt with (using technique 1)

Answer (score 11):

Use [Optimistic Concurrency Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).

Add a versionNumber or versionTimestamp column to the table in question (integer is safest).

User 1 reads record:

```
{id:1, status:unimportant, version:5}
```

User 2 reads record:

```
{id:1, status:unimportant, version:5}
```

User 1 saves record, this increments the version:

```
save {id:1, status:important, version:5}
new value {id:1, status:important, version:6}
```

User 2 tries to save the record they read:

```
save {id:1, status:unimportant, version:5}
ERROR
```

Hibernate/JPA can do this automatically with the `@Version` annotation. If you use Spring Data Rest, it will automatically set the HTTP ETag with this version number

You need to maintain the state of the read record somewhere, generally in session (this is safer than in a hidden form variable).

Comment: Thanks... particularly helpful to know about @Version. One question: why is it safes to store the state in the session? In that case I'd be worried that using the back button could confuse things.

Comment: Session is safer than a hidden form element as the user  wouldnt be able to change the version value. If that's not a concern , then ignore the part about session

Comment: This technique is called [Optimistic offline lock](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html) and it is in SQLAlchemy [as well](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapper_config.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper)

Comment: @paj28 - that link for `SQLAlchemy` doesn't point to anything about optimistic offline locks, and I can't find it in the docs. Did you have a more helpful link, or just pointing people at SQLAlchemy in general?

Comment: @dwanderson I meant the version counter part of that link.

Answer (score 1):

Some Object Relational Mapping (ORM) systems will detect which fields of an object have changed since being loaded from the database, and will construct the SQL update statement to only set those values. ActiveRecord for Ruby on Rails is one such ORM.

The net affect is that fields the user didn't change are not included in the UPDATE command sent to the database. People who update different fields at the same time don't overwrite each others changes.

Depending on which programming language you are using, research which ORMs are available, and see if any of them will only update columns in the database marked "dirty" in your application.

Comment: Hi Greg. Unfortunately, this doesn't help with these kinds of race conditions. If you consider my original example, when Alice saves, the ORM will see the price column as dirty and update it - even though the update is not desired.

Comment: @paj28 The key point in Greg's answer is "_fields the user didn't change_".  Alice didn't change the price, so the ORM wouldn't try to save the "price" value to the database.

Comment: @RossPatterson - how does the ORM know the difference between fields the user changed and stale data from the browser? It doesn't, at least without doing some extra tracking. If you want to edit Greg's answer to include such tracking, or submit another answer, that would be helpful.

Comment: @paj28 some part of the system has to know what the user did, and only store the changes the user made. If the user changed the price, then changed it back, then submitted, this should not count as "something the user changed", because they didn't. If you have a system which requires this level of concurrency control, you have to build it this way. If not, not.

Comment: @nocomprende - Some part, sure - but not the ORM as this answer says

Comment: @paj28 The system I worked with 25 years ago that pulled off this trick was entirely procedural, but it still worked correctly. I am not entirely sure even what an ORM *is*, but I hope that it has not become impossible in the meantime to have a system work this way. After reading a lot about Entity Framework, I think that there is only one person on earth who really understands it: Julie Lerman. (Everyone else who did is probably in the madhouse by now.)

Comment: @nocomprende - The UI knows what's changed. In a typical REST application the UI won't communicate this data to the server. The ORM (which is typically just server-side) has no idea what is a deliberate change and what is stale data. You can code the UI to communicate the information about what's changed - and I presume the app you worked with 25-years ago did something along those lines.

Comment: @paj28 but if the client only transmits a few fields, those should be the only ones that should get persisted. It is OK to distribute the knowledge of what has changed, as long as all the pieces *cooperate*, right? I don't know enough to explain or be sure I understand. I just know it can be done.

Answer (score -2):

Within your example of the webstore, it is crucial that you ensure that two access points are never granted access to the same data point before you commit new changes to the platform or even allow a user to edit the platform.

This means ensuring that the database will not allow multiple users to access the same item at once. There are multiple tools in the space that actually automate this process.

**Tools like (Intel Inspector):**
These tools rely on the data race actually occurring during the profiled execution. Data races are notoriously difficult to detect and debug because they depend on a specific timing to be observed. If the race is not triggered during the execution, these tools will not report the data race.

**Coderrect (A company that I am an intern for):**
Coderrect is working on a data race detector that addresses the limitations of tools like Intel inspector. Our tool, [Coderrect Scanner](https://coderrect.com/download/), does not rely on profiling the execution, but scans the source code directly and alerts the developer about any possible races.